# Better way to structure this JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

So I am making a 2D game using [Firebase](https://firebaseio.com) along with JavaScript and here is part of the saved file. They use JSON to store data.

```
{
    "player" : {
    "github:123123" : {
      "email" : "tester@gmail.com",
      "inventory" : {
        "slot_1" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_10" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_11" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_12" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_13" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_14" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_15" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_16" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_17" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_18" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_19" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_2" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_20" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_3" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_4" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_5" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_6" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_7" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_8" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        },
        "slot_9" : {
          "item_id" : 0,
          "item_qty" : 0
        }
      },
      "lowercase" : "test",
      "map" : 1,
      "member_level" : 2,
      "signed_up" : 1437261263536,
      "uid" : "github:616320",
      "username" : "Test",
      "version" : "1.0.0",
      "x" : 50,
      "y" : 20
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the problem lies how the `inventory` is structured. Is there a better way to structure so it's nicer and neat? I have read up on the [Structuring Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) docs on Firebase but I would appreciate your input.

This could also follow suit for not just inventory but banks and wherever large quanities of slots for items are needed in the game.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a question for [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: I suggest not using these slot_{num}. Instead just fill the array of inventory in case there are items. Then just run a for-loop in javascript, starting with 0 index. Moment it reaches a index that does not exit, throw a break; But that's just how I would do it.

Comment: Not possible to answer this question. This is just opinion based. I use an array structure for my games `[[0,0],[0,0],...]` for faster iteration and being able to easily access certain indices.

Comment: @SebastianNette while it may not be possible to find the best solution to this problem, I think the question itself can be answered, because OP seems to be looking for a more "natural" way to express many values in a object (compared to numbered keys). As arrays are designed for this particular use-case suggesting the use of arrays should be objective enough.

Comment: Due to Firebase's structure, I cannot do that @Verkade89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Your version should work, however I would suggest the following structure:

```
{
    "email" : "tester@gmail.com",
    "inventory" : [{
        "id": 0,
        "amount": 0
    },{
        "id": 0,
        "amount": 0
    },{
        "id": 0,
        "amount": 0
    },{
        "id": 0,
        "amount": 0
    }],
    "lowercase" : "test",
    "map" : 1,
    "memberLevel" : 2,
    "signedUp" : 1437261263536,
    "uid" : "github:616320",
    "username" : "Test",
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    "x" : 50,
    "y" : 20
}
```

Reasoning:

1. In JS camelCase is default for most projects, therefore I would use it here too.
2. You don't need the player attribute and github:* attribute if they are the only one. Safe the JSON to a database for players instead and keep one JSON per player.
3. The data structure of your inventory seems to be better fitting as an array, because you basically use every slot (if not, it's empty) and want to access it by the slot id.
4. If the subobject you describe is in the inventory array there is no need to call every property item, because that's obvious.

Comment: 1. I suppose so, yes. 2. I do because there will be multiple people and I need to separate them from people logging in via twitter, facebook, google and github.
3. Good thinking. Yes.
4. Not sure what this means

Comment: @DanF My 4. point was about the naming you gave the items. If it is in the inventroy, why do you have to name it item_attribute? It's obvious that it is an item, therefore you can leave the "item_" part out of the key.